# Django Thinking User Is Logged In On One Page Only But on The Rest They Are Not

Tags: django, templates, user-profile

So I created a user profile by following this tutorial https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-to-Edit-User-Profile-Both-Django-User-and-Custom-User-Fields/ but every time I go the profile page when not logged in it shows that I am logged in I don't know if django thinks im the user that the profile im viewing.

I tested it by adding this into the base.html

```
    <p>{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    You are logged in
    {% endif %}</p>
```

It doesn't show it on any pages because im not logged in unless I go to view someones profile then it says im logged in which I am not

models.py

```
class UserProfileManager(models.Manager):
    pass


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars', blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default='00/00/0000', null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def age(self):
        dob = self.date_of_birth
        tod = datetime.date.today()
        my_age = (tod.year - dob.year) - int((tod.month, tod.day) < (dob.month, dob.day))
        return my_age


def createProfile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.created(user=kwargs['instance'])
        post_save.connect(createProfile, sender=User)
```

views.py

```
def public_profile_view(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.all()
    # date_joined = request.user.date_joined
    # last_login = request.user.last_login

    context = {
        'user': user,
        'userprofile': userprofile,
        # 'date_joined': date_joined,
        # 'last_login': last_login,
    }

    return render(request, "/account/profile/public_profile.html", context)


def profile_edit_view(request):
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.userprofile)

        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form = form.save()
            custom_form = profile_form.save(False)
            custom_form.user = user_form
            custom_form.save()
            return redirect('profile_urls:public_profile')
    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)
        args = {'userprofile': userprofile,}
        # args.update(csrf(request))
        args['form'] = form
        args['profile_form'] = profile_form
        return render(request, "/account/profile/profile_edit.html", args)
```

forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')


class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(label='Date of Birth')

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('avatar', 'location', 'website', 'date_of_birth', 'bio', 'website')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        location = cleaned_data.get('location')
        website = cleaned_data.get('website')
        date_of_birth = cleaned_data.get('date_of_birth')
        bio = cleaned_data.get('bio')
        website = cleaned_data.get('website')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is happending because you are passing user object in `public_profile.html` by doing following

```
def public_profile_view(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

to check wheather actual user is logged in or not use `request.user`

```
<p>{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    You are logged in
    {% endif %}</p>
```